SpringBoot 3.3.6 @ConfigurationProperties injecting a null object into constructor
I'm upgrading a spring boot project from 2.7.x to 3.3.6.
Hitting a problem with a test using ApplicationContextRunner where the bean being injected into the constructor of a @ConfigurationProperties instance is null. The object injected into a @Bean method is not null.
The test below passes on 2.7.x but fails on 3.3.6. There appears to be a change with how the @ConfigurationProperties are being loaded in 3.x. When loaded as part of the full application (instead of the test ApplicationContextRunner/TrivialConfiguration) the non-null KafkaProperties is injected into the wrapper.
Can anyone suggest what changes I need to make? I can't see anything directly related in the migration guides.
@Getter
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.kafka")
public class KafkaPropertiesWrapper {
    private final KafkaProperties kafkaProperties;

    public KafkaPropertiesWrapper(KafkaProperties kafkaProperties) {
        this.kafkaProperties = kafkaProperties;
    }
}

@Getter
public class AnotherWrapper {
    private final KafkaProperties kafkaProperties;

    public AnotherWrapper(KafkaProperties kafkaProperties) {
        this.kafkaProperties = kafkaProperties;
    }
}

class KafkaWrapperTest {
    @EnableConfigurationProperties({KafkaPropertiesWrapper.class, KafkaProperties.class})
    private static class TrivialConfiguration {
        @Bean
        AnotherWrapper anotherWrapper(KafkaProperties kafkaProperties) {
            return new AnotherWrapper(kafkaProperties);
        }
    }

    private ApplicationContextRunner contextRunner = new ApplicationContextRunner()
            .withUserConfiguration(TrivialConfiguration.class);

    @Test
    void startsOk() {
        contextRunner
                .run(context -> {
                            assertThat(context).hasSingleBean(KafkaProperties.class);
                            assertThat(context).hasSingleBean(KafkaPropertiesWrapper.class);
                            KafkaPropertiesWrapper kafkaPropertiesWrapper = context.getBean(KafkaPropertiesWrapper.class);
                            assertThat(kafkaPropertiesWrapper.getKafkaProperties()).isNotNull();
                        }
                );
    }
}


As of Spring Boot 3.0, the constructor needs to be annotated with @Autowired to indicate that it should be used for dependency injection rather than property binding.

thanks. I'd thought I'd tried that already. Must have done something wrong with it but had discounted it as a red herring because the main app was working.
Changes I've made are to add an "@Configuration" stereotype to the KafkaPropertiesWrapper and an "@Autowired" annotation to the constructor
